# How to remove the the seconds from given time in shell script

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed, cut

Hi i am trying to remove the seconds in the given time format .

```
time format = 02:59:46 PM

export hello="02:59:46 PM"

i want it as 02:59 PM

tried command :  echo $hello | cut -d':' -f1,2,4
```

above command not working because the delimiter is space for last field.

can some help me to extract the desired output using any cut,awk,sed command.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could perform substitution with parameter expansion itself with your sample.

```
hello="02:59:46 PM"
echo "${hello/:[0-9][0-9] / }"
02:59 PM
```

***From documentation:*** [BASH parameter expansion substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

> ${parameter/pattern/string} The pattern is expanded to produce a
> pattern just as in filename expansion. Parameter is expanded and the
> longest match of pattern against its value is replaced with string.
> The match is performed according to the rules described below (see
> Pattern Matching). If pattern begins with ‘/’, all matches of pattern
> are replaced with string. Normally only the first match is replaced.
> If pattern begins with ‘#’, it must match at the beginning of the
> expanded value of parameter. If pattern begins with ‘%’, it must match
> at the end of the expanded value of parameter. If string is null,
> matches of pattern are deleted and the / following pattern may be
> omitted. If the nocasematch shell option (see the description of shopt
> in The Shopt Builtin) is enabled, the match is performed without
> regard to the case of alphabetic characters. If parameter is ‘@’ or
> ‘*’, the substitution operation is applied to each positional
> parameter in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list. If
> parameter is an array variable subscripted with ‘@’ or ‘*’, the
> substitution operation is applied to each member of the array in turn,
> and the expansion is the resultant list.

Answer (score 1):

With `bash` and its [Parameter Expansion](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
hello="02:59:46 PM"
echo "${hello:0:5}${hello:8:3}"
```

Output:

```
02:59 PM
```

Answer (score 1):

Using date command:

```
$ hello="02:59:46 PM"
$ date --date="20200101 $hello" "+%I:%M %p"
02:59 PM
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` for that following way, let content of `file.txt` be:

```
02:59:46 PM
```

then:

```
awk '{$1=substr($1,1,5);print}' file.txt
```

output:

```
02:59 PM
```

or if you wish using with `echo` then do:

```
echo '02:59:46 PM' > awk '{$1=substr($1,1,5);print}'
```

Explanation: by default awk split each lines (1 line in this case) into fields on spaces. I use [substr](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) function to get 5 first characters (digit, digit, colon, digit, digit) of `1`st field (`$1`), then assign it to said field. Then I `print` whole changed line.

You can use GNU `sed` for that following way:

```
echo '02:59:46 PM' > sed 's/:[0-9][0-9] / /'
```

Explanation: replace colon-digit-digit-space with space.